Where should I put “not” in the sentence 'The person admits to ___ having ___ read the book'?
I have three forms that I can think of for this sentence:

The person admits to not having read the book.
The person admits to having not read the book.
The person admits not to have read the book.

Which, if any is most grammatically correct and why? Is there a better form than any of these?

Did you mean to use "to having read" in all three of those, not just in the first two? Why did you switch to an infinitive?

@tchrist I thought “not to having read” sounded wrong. If that is the best option, I’m open to it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This really doesn't constitute an answer on its own, but might be helpful anyway: Google Ngrams shows results exclusively for your first alternative ("admits to not having read"): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admits+to+not+having+read%2Cadmits+to+having+not+read%2Cadmits+not+to+have+read&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 I personally think all 3 versions sound fine, but given the lack of results for the other two, it seems like the first is probably the best choice.

At one time, we were cautioned to not split an infinitive oops. However, that was based on Latin grammar. All three sound fine to me!

It's difficult to confidently assess naturalness in a sentence where some other part of the sentence itself is unnatural. "The person admits" is unnatural. Could you [edit] it to something natural like, "The interviewer admitted...", or if there's a real context you intend to use it in, just give that sentence?

"She admits not to having read the book" would be correct only as part of a longer sentence like "she admits not to having read the book but to having listened to its audiobook".

@QuackE.Duck Thank you for this comment. Google Ngrams looks like a great tool for figuring out these kinds of problems. Grammar blogs by English scholars often seem to judge what is and isn't correct by its prevalence or how long ago its precedent was established. Now I can find that info myself!

@ryang The OP's example says, "...not to have read...", not "... not to having read..."

@gotube Sure. Could you comment on the difference between those two alternatives (or create such an answer below)?

To help assess the naturalness of the negated gerund, I've replaced "The person admits" with something more natural:


The interviewer admitted to not having read the book.
The interviewer admitted to having not read the book.
The interviewer admitted not to have read the book.


Sentence 1 is 100% natural, and means "accept blame".
Sentence 2 is fine, and has the same meaning, but is just slightly less natural, especially in writing. When sentence 1 is available, I'd need a compelling reason to use sentence 2.
Sentence 3 would be acceptable in unprepared English, such as a natural conversation, but in writing it's a mistake. Without the negation, it's unacceptable:

*The interviewer admitted to have read the book.

The intervening "not" somewhat hides that the grammar is bad, but I'd expect a good editor or standardized exam marker to flag sentence 3 as an error.

So, in general, removing the negation can at least help me eliminate incorrect sentence formulations?

@Eric In this case, and in most cases yes, but it's not a 100% reliable rule. There are situations where removing the negation would lead you to an incorrect conclusion because the structure specifically requires something in the "not" place. For instance, (1) "There's not much milk in the fridge" is correct, but, (2) "There's much milk in the fridge" is at best unnatural and highly marked. Yet it's incorrect to conclude from this that sentence 1 is incorrect.
